# PXE boot timeouts setting

Tags: boot, pxe

I trying to set up a PXE boot server. Everything is working but when the client is booting after the pxelinux.0 is loaded there is a `boot:` prompt.

[image: boot:]

1. When I hit enter to the pxelinux.cfg/default enter the next menu where is another Automatic boot in 120s countdown.
2. If I no not hit enter after 1-2 mins it goes to the same menu as above.

It will be cool if somebody will share with us how to setup these 2(two) timeouts? Thanks so much!

[image: Automatic boot timeout]

```
PROMPT 0
TIMEOUT 50
# Default boot option to use
DEFAULT menu.c32
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need the `TIMEOUT` setting for both of these delays.

Here is a simple `pxelinux.cfg/default` configuration that seems to match your description.

```
PROMPT 1
TIMEOUT 100
DEFAULT menu.c32
LABEL Boot_1
LABEL Boot_2
```

When this config is loaded, the `boot:` prompt will be displayed for 10 seconds.  After 10 seconds (or if I hit enter) a menu with the two boot options will appear and display `Automatic boot in 10 seconds...`.

The [documentation for `TIMEOUT`](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=SYSLINUX) states

> this directive indicates how long to pause at the boot: prompt until
> booting automatically, in units of 1/10 s

The [menu.c32 system](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Comboot/menu.c32) also uses the `TIMEOUT` configuration, which is why the setting affects both.

> The menu system honours the TIMEOUT command. If TIMEOUT is specified,
> it will execute the ONTIMEOUT command if one exists

You might also be interested in `TOTALTIMEOUT` and `ONTIMEOUT`.

I find this configuration to be a bit strange.  If you want to get rid of the `boot:` prompt completely then you can use `PROMPT 0`.

Comment: Initially when I started this I followed the sources you indicated, however not always works as in the book. I changed to PROMPT 0 in the first place but no difference. Indeed strange. Thanks so much and I will post the outcome.